# Estructura de minerías de datos visual studio 2022

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2019, visual-studio-2022

Tengo un proyecto de analysis services en visual studio 2022, necesito realizar un proceso de minería pero no me aparece la carpeta de estructura de minerías de datos, sin embargo si realizo la apertura del proyecto en visual studio 2019 si me aparece tal carpeta pero al momento de ejecutar el proyecto me saca un error con la versión de analysis services:

Errors in the metadata manager. This version of Analysis Services does not support Data Mining and creating/altering of Data Mining structures/models is not supported

Existe alguna forma de poder crear estos proyectos en el explorador de soluciones de visual studio 2022, o de que forma puedo arreglar el problema con visual studio 2019

Asi se ve mi explorador de soluciones desde visual 2019:

[image: Así se ve mi explorador de soluciones desde visual 2019:]

Desde visual 2022 se ve así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este error me aparece en visual 2019 cuando trato de ejecutar la mineria:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No parece ser un problema de Visual Studio propiamente. El mensaje de error indica que el servidor no soporta minería de datos.

> Errors in the metadata manager. **This version of Analysis Services does not support Data Mining** and creating/altering of Data Mining structures/models is not supported

El resaltado es mío.

Mi traducción libre sería:

> Errores en el administrador de metadatos. **Esta versión de Analysis Services no soporta minería de datos** y la creación/modificación de estructuras/modelos de minería de datos no está soportada.

Probablemente no estás conectado a una versión de Analysis Services dónde ya no existe la minería de datos. La [documentación](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/analysis-services/data-mining/data-mining-ssas?view=asallproducts-allversions) lo advierte de entrada:

> La minería de datos estaba en desuso en SQL Server 2017 Analysis Services y ahora se descontinuó en SQL Server 2022 Analysis Services.

Si quieres tener acceso a esta característica, tienes que conectarte a una versión anterior de Analysis Services, donde aún esté soportada, así como utilizar una versión de visual studio que aún permita crear y modificar dichos modelos.